# Installing VMs in CentOS 7 host from ISO?

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, qemu, linux-kvm, centos-7

I'm trying to install a CentOS 7 guest in a CentOS 7 host, using text only. I'm using simillar commands as:

```
virt-install --name centos7 --ram 1024 --disk path=/var/kvm/images/centos7.img,size=25 --vcpus 1 --os-type linux --os-variant rhel7 --network bridge=br0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --location '/mnt/sdb1/ISOs/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1503-01.iso ' --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

It creates the virtual disk, and then goes on until saying

> trying to set up timer as Virtual Wire IRQ

where it hangs indefinitely.

I googled around, found that [Red Hat users experiened the same](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=502058), but the workaround doesn't work here, also found that there was a bug on Ubuntu that was fixed. Could it be a bug on CentOS? What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: --ram 1024
are You sure it's enough? Try 2048.

Comment: 2048 would be the host's total. Either way, for a system without GUI seems more than enough.